# VBA code to open two files using an application

Tags: vba, shell, automation

I'm relatively new at VBA, and I am developing this excel based tool that creates two .xls files, whose paths are saved in two variables. The next step is the user has to select these two files, right click and select an application called **Compare**.

I was wondering if this process could be automated using Shell commands in VBA. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Assuming the compare takes two files as arguments, just do something like this:

```
Public Function OpenCompare(strFileOne As String, strFileTwo As String)
     Dim x As Variant
    x = Shell("Compare.exe " & strFileOne & " " & strFileTwo, vbNormalFocus)
End Function
```

Comment: Note that `x` is the ID of the task, not the output of the program.

Comment: Probably best to quote the paths to deal with spaces